# How to have one list box present data based on selection of first one?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, picturebox

I'm making a windows form with 2 list boxes. My plan is for the user to have the option to add/edit/remove from both list boxes. When a user selects an option from the first list (a selection of car names i.e. Mazda 3), the second list box will show all the data that would be entered based off that of the first selection (my idea is to keep service records for each vehicle; this box also will have the option to add/edit/remove). How should I go about having the second list box show items based on the selection of the first list box?

Is a multidimensional array the best way to do this? I also plan on having a picture box that will show a picture that the user can upload and will be view-able based on the selection of the SECOND list box.

Thanks

Comment: I imagine you could capture the change event for the first control and use it to populate the second control.  Have you tried anything?  Where did you get stuck?

Comment: No, I haven't really spent much time on it. I got to that point and then took a break (just a small side project I'm doing for myself - and others if they wish to use it). My thought process was to have 2 string arrays and based on the index on the item selected, I can then go to that position in the second array. But that'll only return one item as well. Whereas that i'th item may have 30 sub-items (in the 2nd list box).

Comment: Well, I guess first you need to define what your data is and how you organize it.  You'll need to logically be able to filter your second set of data based on the value selected from the first set.  First define your data, then build the interface to view that data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not really clear on what it actually is you're trying to do, but from my understanding you have a list of cars, and for every car on that list, there is a list of service records?

If this is the case you could do something like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    List<string> cars = new List<string>()
    {
        "Mazda 3",
        "Mazda 6",
        "VW Polo",
        "VW Golf"
    };

    List<string> Mazda3 = new List<string>()
    {
        "12-04-2008",
        "14-03-2010",
        "20-05-2012",

    };

    List<string> Mazda6 = new List<string>()
    {
        "12-08-2012",
        "14-07-2014",
        "03-09-2016",
    };

    List<string> VWPolo = new List<string>()
    {
        "Some Date",
        "Some Date",
        "Some Date",
    };

    List<string> VWGolf = new List<string>()
    {
        "Some Date",
        "Some Date",
        "Some Date",
    };

    List<List<string>> ServiceLists = new List<List<string>>();


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ServiceLists.Add(Mazda3);
        ServiceLists.Add(Mazda6);
        ServiceLists.Add(VWPolo);
        ServiceLists.Add(VWGolf);

        Cars_listBox.DataSource = cars;
    }

    private void Cars_listBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ServiceRecords_listBox.DataSource = ServiceLists[Cars_listBox.SelectedIndex];
    }
}
```

In this example the listBoxes are created in the designer

Comment: Yes this will be something similar to what I have in mind. However, the vehicle names won't be known so it can't be hardcoded. It's whatever the user would want to put in. So some people name their car, lets say "Sally", then they are able to just put in "Sally" and have a list of all the service records in the next list box.

Comment: @Ghart14 In that case you need an input box, and just add the inputs to the list like this: `cars.Add(stringItem);`

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide the code of what you have so far? Without knowing that, I would say you can have a function invoked by the change in the first list box

```
`private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if(listBox1.Text == "mazda 3")
         //do something here with listbox2
 }`
```

Comment: I have no code currently that goes toward the solution I want. I was more so looking for a pointer towards getting 2 list boxes to work correctly together and how I should keep my store the data, whether in string arrays or multi-dimensional array, etc. I responded to David above about what I have going.